# How to load images from csv file into windows phone?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a tab delimited text file which contains 19 columns and around 45000 rows. I imported this data into sql server 2005 and exported into csv file. In this table there is a column named "icon_url" which consists of many jpeg links with size 100x100px. What i need to do is, i need to get this data as grid view shown below. What is the best way to load this data quickly? Is csv format good for loading data? please write in detail.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, csv is not a "good" format. That's a simple format, though.

If you just want to store a couple of image URIs that will not change, you can either store it in a txt file (one line per uri)... this solution is the simpler (and quite equivalent to a csv file, but "safer": nobody will do a mistake like creating a new column or something else that could happen with excel).

...Or you want something a bit more maintainable, you could use an embbeded database (if you want the data to rest on your phone). You may find some tutorials about it on google [like this one](http://www.adambenoit.com/development/entity-framework-windows-phone-part-1/)

Or you could load serialized data using [XmlSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s92ee1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To answer your question, that (ugly) code should do the trick (not tested):

**Xaml**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="items">
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <UniformGrid Columns="4"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Height="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Source="{Binding}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
            </ItemsControl>
```

**Cs**

```
items.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines("yourCsvFile.csv").Select(s=>s.Trim(';')).Skip(1); // skip the header...
```

Comment: then which format is better one for this task? I can change it from Sql server.

Comment: It depends where you want the URI list to be stored. On the phone ? Remotely ? moreover, why did you tag this question "sqlite" ? ps: see my edit